# How to handle long-running operations in an Rx.NET Websocket Client

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

I've built a websocket client using Rx.NET. The client handles both pending requests (requests waiting for their corresponding responses within a specific timeout period), and subscriptions (continous stream of messages).

If a message takes 5 seconds to be processed as it involves some database operations, it shouldn't slow the server processing pipeline overall. What do you think is best:
offload the data handlers/processors
process server messages concurrently (in parallel)
i.e.

```cs
public static IDisposable SubscribeAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Task> onNext) =>
    source
        .Select(item => Observable.FromAsync(() => onNext(item)))
        .Merge()
        .Subscribe();
```

instead of

```cs
public static IDisposable SubscribeAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Task> onNext) =>
    source
        .Select(item => Observable.FromAsync(async () => await onNext(item)))
        .Concat()
        .Subscribe();
```

To me it sounds like it's best to keep the message processing sequential and not in parallel, and to offload the data handlers because this way I could easily move the processing power to another machine. What do you guys think?

I'm using [Marfusios' websocket client](https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client) library:

```cs
public sealed class CqgWebSocketClient : WebsocketClient
{
    public CqgWebSocketClient(Uri url, Func<ClientWebSocket>? clientFactory = null) : base(url, clientFactory)
    {
    }

    public CqgWebSocketClient(Uri url,
        int reconnectTimeInSeconds,
        Func<DisconnectionInfo, Task> disconnect,
        Func<ReconnectionInfo, Task> reconnect,
        Func<ClientWebSocket>? clientFactory = null) : base(url, clientFactory)
    {
        ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        ErrorReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(reconnectTimeInSeconds);

        // TODO: Should these be synchronized?
        DisconnectionHappened.SubscribeAsync(disconnect);
        ReconnectionHappened.SubscribeAsync(reconnect);
    }
}
```